# Kotlin maven plugin not generating no-arg constructor

Tags: maven, kotlin, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have following maven plugin config:

```
         <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5.6</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
                <artifactId>kotlin-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${kotlin.version}</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>compile</id>
                        <phase>process-sources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>compile</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <args>
                                <arg>-Xjsr305=strict</arg>
                            </args>
                            <compilerPlugins>
                                <plugin>spring</plugin>
                                <plugin>jpa</plugin>
                            </compilerPlugins>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
<!-- ALSO tried following instead of EXECUTIONS section above -->
<!--                <configuration>-->
<!--                    <args>-->
<!--                        <arg>-Xjsr305=strict</arg>-->
<!--                    </args>-->
<!--                    <compilerPlugins>-->
<!--                        <plugin>spring</plugin>-->
<!--                        <plugin>jpa</plugin>-->
<!--                        <plugin>all-open</plugin>-->
<!--                    </compilerPlugins>-->
<!--                    <pluginOptions>-->
<!--                        <option>all-open:annotation=javax.persistence.Entity</option>-->
<!--                        <option>all-open:annotation=javax.persistence.Embeddable</option>-->
<!--                        <option>all-open:annotation=javax.persistence.MappedSuperclass</option>-->
<!--                    </pluginOptions>-->
<!--                </configuration>-->
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
                        <artifactId>kotlin-maven-allopen</artifactId>
                        <version>${kotlin.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
                        <artifactId>kotlin-maven-noarg</artifactId>
                        <version>${kotlin.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
```

I am new to Kotlin, so I am not sure if the above config is correct. However, the above config is suggested everywhere in order to generate no-args constructors. But now when I try to write following code:

`var myEntity = MyEntity()`

The IDE (IntelliJ) asks me to provide all the parameters which don't have a default value set in the MyEntity class which btw is annotated by @Entity. I also get similar error when I run `mvn compile` from the terminal. What am I missing?

Comment: what happens if you build the code? does `mvn` fail? is the error just shown by the IDE?

Comment: as mentioned mvn compile fails with the same error that the IDE shows.